# scikit-learn feature ranking returns identical values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm using scikit-learn's [RFECV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV) class to perform feature selection. I'm interested in identifying the relative importance of a bunch of variables. However, scikit-learn returns the same ranking (1) for multiple variables. This can also be seen in their example code:

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
>>> from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVR
>>> X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
>>> estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
>>> selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
>>> selector = selector.fit(X, y)
>>> selector.support_ 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False])
>>> selector.ranking_
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 5])
```

Is there a way I can make scikit-learn also identify the relative importance between the top features?

I'm happy to increase the number of trees or similar if that's needed. Related to this, is there a way to see the confidence of this ranking?

Comment: I think this question would me more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fair. I'd be happy to have it moved. If any moderators see this, please feel free to move it :)

Comment: I think most scikit-learn questions are on SO, so I think I'd keep it here.

Comment: You are using linear SVR, you can try changing it to 'poly'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The goal of `RFECV` is to select the optimum number of features, so it does cross-validation over the number of features selected.
In your case, it selected to keep 5 features.
Then the model is refit on the whole data set until only 5 features remain.
These are not removed, so they are not ranked in RFE.

You could get a ranking for all features by just running RFE

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.svm import SVR
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFE(estimator, step=1, n_features_to_select=1)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
selector.ranking_
```

> array([ 4,  3,  5,  1,  2, 10,  8,  7,  6,  9])

You might ask yourself why the ranking from the cross-validation is not kept, which computed a ranking for all features. However, for each split in the cross-validation, the features might have been ranked differently.
So alternatively RFECV could return 5 different rankings and you could compare them. That's not the interface, though (but would also be easy to accomplish with RFE and doing the cv yourself).

On a different note, this might not be the best way to compute the influence of the features and looking at coefficients directly or maybe permutation importance might be more informative.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm always a bit skeptical of using feature importances (especially when reading e.g. https://medium.com/turo-engineering/how-not-to-use-random-forest-265a19a68576). At least with CV and a metric, you know exactly what you're measuring :)

Comment: How come there's no sklearn method that simply iterates over all the features, and removes them one by one by examining CV performance?

That's the definition of backward feature selection I know from textbooks, and it should produce a robust ranking across all features. That's what I expected `RFECV` to be doing.

Comment: Backward feature selection is not the same as recursive feature selection. RFE is cheaper, it uses feature importance / coefficients. There's a PR for backward feature selection or you can use mlxtend. How come: no one had time / prioritized implementing and reviewing it.